# NativeScript Angular Login with Tab Navigation debugging

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I followed the writeup [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation) to set up my NativeScript app using a login page that then takes you into a tabbed navigation setup.

I am running NativeScript Sidekick with an iPhone emulator for development. The writeup and the included [git repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng) use lazy loading for all of the components and modules that will be navigated to via the tabbed navigation. With this setup, I am unable to inspect the source of the modules that were lazy loaded using the Chrome Dev tools. Does anyone know of a way to do the same thing without lazy loading or to actually be able to inspect and debug modules that were lazy loaded?

Comment: Are you saying you are unable to locate the modules at all in chrome dev tools, with & without lazy loading?

Comment: Without lazy loading I was able to go into chrome dev tools -> sources -> webpack and inspect all of the modules and components of the app. With lazy loading the only components I was able to see at the ones that were not lazy loaded. Of course, When I tried to replicate this behavior today it is no longer happening. I can now see all modules and components. It may be that I opened the chrome debugger after the modules were lazy loaded.